How to Fix "Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED" in Node.js Firebase Firestore Backend?
    require('dotenv').config();
    const {initializeApp}=require('firebase-admin/app');
    const { getFirestore, collection,doc} = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,\
      ...
    }
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const db = getFirestore(app);
    async function addData(username) {
      try {
        const nameRef = db.collection('names').doc(); 
        await nameRef.set({
          name: username
        });
        console.log("Data added successfully!");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding document:", error);
      }
    }

    module.exports={addData}

Output
Error adding document: Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
Expected:
I'm encountering the "Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials" when attempting to connect to Firestore from my Node.js backend using Firebase. Could you help me identify and resolve this issue?

Make sure you've console.log('firebaseConfig', firebaseConfig) just to see if your env values are being set correctly.
